# Array search strategy

Tags: javascript

The task is the following - in `input` there are some English letters which I want to replace by values located in `jap` and put in `outputArr` according to dictionary in `eng` (same position).

But I really don't understand how to make such loop / if to make it work.

```
<script>
var input = "agde";
var inputArr = input.split('');
var outputArr = [];
var eng= ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g"];
var jap = ["あ","び","を","ご","で","え","よ"];
```

Comment: I split  input = "agde" and get letters in inputArr and after it i take every english letter and replace it by japaneese letter with the same array position  in var outputArr = ["あ","よ", "ご", "で"]                                                                           "a" = "あ"
"b" =  "び"
"c" =  "を"
"d" = "ご"
"e" = "で"
"f" = "え"
"g" = "よ"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `indexOf` function to get the corresponding index, access it via `[]` and `map` the result into your `outputArr`:

```js
var eng = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"];
var jap = ["あ", "び", "を", "ご", "で", "え", "よ"];

var input = "agde";
var inputArr = input.split("");

const outputArr = inputArr.map((char) => jap[eng.indexOf(char)]);
console.log(outputArr);
```

Comment: Well this answer was first and will be accepted in 3 mins. Thanks all for help!!!

Answer (score 5):

First combine `eng` and `jap` into a lookup table (a plain object):

```js
var eng = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g"];
var jap = ["あ","び","を","ご","で","え","よ"];
var translation = Object.fromEntries(eng.map((letter, i) => [letter, jap[i]]));


// Now translate an example input
var input = "agde";
var output = Array.from(input, letter => translation[letter]).join("");
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can map the array and use the `indexOf` method from Arrays to find the index of English alphabet and use it against the jap array

```js
var input = "agde";
var eng= ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g"];
var jap = ["あ","び","を","ご","で","え","よ"];

const getJapOut = ([...input]) => [...input].map(value => jap[eng.indexOf(value)])

console.log(getJapOut(input));
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) we can get the corresponding Japanese character and use [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create a new array with the new characters.

```js
var input = "agde";
var inputArr = input.split("");
var outputArr = [];
var eng = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"];
var jap = ["あ", "び", "を", "ご", "で", "え", "よ"];

let output = inputArr.map((char) => {
  const index = eng.findIndex((letter) => letter === char);
  return jap[index];
});
console.log(output);
```